# Is there any Alternative of CCSpriteBatchNode in android cocos2d

Tags: java, cocos2d-android

Question is self explanatory, 
again I need an alternativs in cocos2d android to use CCSpriteBatchNode

any help is appreciated .

Answer (score 3, accepted):

CCSpriteBatchNode is a renamed CCSpriteSheet 
using CCSpriteSheet should work